# Same view runs fast in DB but slow in program

Tags: c#, sql, query-performance

I encounter a problem using SQL Server and C# and I need help.

I have a C# program that calls a view and shows the result in a  grid. 
I use two databases with same structure to test the performance. 
DB1 is on a strong system with less records, in contrast DB2 is on a weaker system with large number of records. The view runs significantly faster on DB1 when I run it on the SQL server engine. However, when I use the application to show the view, the result is reverse. When the application is connected to DB2 the result is shown significantly faster than when the same application is connected to DB1.

Thanks in advance any input is appreciated.
Maryann

Comment: Do you have the execution plans for both?

Comment: Hi David,Thanks so much for getting back to me. I just checked the execution plans and I see that they are quite different! I am not sure  why!

Comment: If you share them with us, we may be able to help!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help David. It is a very large one, I tried to provide a figure of it but this forum does not allow me to upload it. Would a xml format of the execution plan be useful? Otherwise could you please tell me how can I share it?

Comment: ah, yes - you may have restrictions as a new person.  Certainly you could put them somewhere else recognizable, like Google docs, and share that link.